# GCE VM instance no longer able to do outbound requests

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a Ubuntu(14.04) VM instance that I can SSH into.  It has no iptable rules and ufw disabled.  Other VMs in the network are accessible.  Outbound requests are timing out.  Restarting the VM didn't work.

tl;dr I can't ping google.com from a VM.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Can you SSH to it from the GCE network it's on, or from a machine external to GCE? Can you post the traceroute output?

Comment: I figured it out.  It's because I took off the ephemeral IP.  It takes a while after external IP removal for the vm to be unable to send outbound requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the external IP will make the VM unable to make outbound requests.  The effect is not immediate.